# Comparing the number events from this january to previous the five januarys

Tags: statistical-significance, outliers

Hi sorry if this question is quite silly but lets say that for the past 5 years I have collected data on the **amount of times** a customer has had to wait longer than 10 minutes to be served in the month of April.

If I then collect the data for this April and notice that it seems higher than usual.

1. Is there a test that I can run which can tell me if it is significantly higher?
2. Could I run the test on the percentages rather than the raw numbers i.e. (no.waiting/total served)*100

For example:

| Year | percentage of customers kept waiting |
| --- | --- |
| 2015 | 4 |
| 2016 | 5 |
| 2017 | 4 |
| 2018 | 3 |
| 2019 | 6 |

If in 2020 the percentage of customers kept waiting was 12% how could i check if this is an abnormally large percentage compared to previous years

Comment: We need the raw counts! Can you add those? as an edit to the post

Comment: Ahh i just made up the numbers here to get an undrstanding of what test to use, would it help to also have random raw data?

Comment: Yes, simulated example data is very useful! Please provide some.